# How to efficiently mask tensors in tensorflow only given the indices of the last axis?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, mask, keras-2

Imagine I have a tensor of shape `(batch_size, a, ... , c, d, e)`where are a, ... ,c,d,e are defined integers. For example `(batch_size, 500, 3, 2, 2, 69)` or `(batch_size, 2, 2)`.

My question is for all tensors but let's stick to the example of `tensor1.get_shape() = (?, 500, 3, 2, 2, 69)`

Given that I have `tensor2` with `tensor2.get_shape() = (?, 500, 3, 2, 2, 14)` containing indices of the last axis of `tensor1`, I have 2 problems:

1) I want to construct a mask for `tensor1` of shape `(?, 500, 3, 2, 2, 69)` from `tensor2`. For example a possible row along the last axis for `tensor2` would be `[1,8,3,68,2,4,58,19,20,21,26,48,56,11]` but since `tensor2` is constructed from `tensor1` these indices vary for new input. These are the indices of the last axis that have to be kept of `tensor1`. Everything else has to be masked out.

2) given that I have the mask of shape  `(?, 500, 3, 2, 2, 69)` for `tensor1`, how do I mask out the undesired values while maintaining the batch size dimension? The masked out tensor should have shape `(?, 500, 3, 2, 2, 14)`.

Answers in keras or numpy would also be neat, although knowing how to do it in numpy wouldn't solve my problem, I'd still like to know.

Answer (score 0):

answer to 1:
`tf.gather_nd(mask, [tf.range(tf.shape(tensor1)[0])[:,None, None, None, None, None],tf.range(tf.shape(tensor1)[1])[:,None, None, None, None],tf.range(tf.shape(tensor1)[2])[:,None, None, None],tf.range(tf.shape(tensor1)[3])[:,None, None],tf.range(tf.shape(tensor1)[4])[:,None],tensor2])`

There is probably no solution to 2. I will try pytorch.

Comment: You can use tf.where to do the masking, I think